# Prob. 4, Chap. 3 in Baby Rudin: How to show that these are the limit superior and the limit inferior?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

Here's Prob. 4, Chap. 3 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Find the upper and lower limit of the sequence $\left\{ s_n \right\}$ defined by $$s_1 = 0; \ s_{2m} = \frac{s_{2m-1}}{2}; \ s_{2m+1} = \frac{1}{2}+ s_{2m}.$$

My effort:

> We note that $s_1 = 0$, $s_2 = 0$, $s_3 = \frac{1}{2}$, $s_4 = \frac{1}{4}$, $s_5 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4}$, $s_6 = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8}$, $s_7 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8}$, $s_8 =  \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16}$, $s_9 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16}$, $s_{10} = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{32}$, $s_{11} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{32}$, $s_{12} = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{32} + \frac{1}{64}$, and continuing in this way we obtain 
>   $$s_{2m} = \frac{1}{2}- \frac{1}{2^m} \ \mbox{ and } \ s_{2m+1} = 1- \frac{1}{2^m}  $$ for $m = 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots$. So $$\lim_{m \to \infty} s_{2m} = \frac{1}{2} \ \mbox{ and } \ \lim_{m \to \infty} s_{2m+1} = 1.$$

Am I right?

Using the above, how to rigorously prove that $$\lim\inf_{n \to \infty} s_n = \frac{1}{2} \ \mbox{ and } \ \lim\sup_{n\to\infty} s_n = 1?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there exists a sub sequence of $\{s_n\}$ converges to a point $s$. That is $\{s_{n_k} \}\to s$. Define $S_1$ as the set of terms with odd indices. That is, $n_k$ is odd and similarly $S_2$ for even terms. Note that either $S_1$ or $S_2$ has infinite elements, but not both. Hence, $s=1$ or $s=1/2$. Thus for any limit $s$ of sub sequence we have $1/2\leq s\leq 1$ and the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Show inductively that
$$
s_{2n}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^n}\quad\text{and}\quad s_{2n+1}=1-\frac{1}{2^n}.
$$

Comment: @ Yiorgos S. Smyrils: He has already shown that part in the question.

Comment: He has not. He observed it.